# One File per Logger in Log4net

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I would like to configure a FileAppender (or similar) that saves the message from each different logger to a different file, preferably named as the logger. The issue is that the number of loggers and their names are determined during application initialization. I would really appreciate any solution...even better if I dont have to write my own appender.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easy enough to extract the appenders attached to a logger, and hence to set the file name for each. What do you mean though by " the number of loggers and their names are determined during application initialization"?

Comment: We have a variable number of entities we want to monitor and now our client wants a different log file for each entity. The loggers are created dynamically with the name of the entity...I think this is not the best approach but we are dealing with legacy code and this new requirement from the client. Thanks